# VB.Net IO performance

Tags: vb.net, performance, io

Having read [this page](http://www.osnews.com/story/5602/Nine_Language_Performance_Round-up_Benchmarking_Math_File_I_O/page3/), I can't believe that VB.Net has such a terrible performance when it comes to I/O.

Is this still true today? How does the .Net Framework 2.0 perform in terms of I/O (that's the version I'm targeting)?

Comment: Because it comes with many other software package, and more users already have it pre-installed. Plus, I don't need any of the new functionalities in .net 3+

Comment: Did you read the comments? Seems like the VB.NET code used legacy functions instead of native .NET methods, which should make it the same as the C# results.

Comment: I'd want to review that benchmarking code - even on 1.1, VB.Net and C# *should* have the same file IO perfromance, and yet that page claims not. Unfortunately, the link to the code is no longer available.

Comment: My mistake - the code just took a long time to load. As Martin says, they're using the Legacy VB interop way of doing File IO, not .Net methods...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware of shoddy benchmarks without peer review.  The file I/O [benchmark code](http://www.cowell-shah.com/research/benchmark/code) uses the old VB6 compatibility I/O functions, PrintLine() and LineInput().  Yes, they are not cheap.  The bench mark also doesn't attempt to do anything to measure *real* I/O performance, it doesn't flush the file system cache.  Somewhat understandable perhaps, that would measure the speed of the disk and every language would perform the same, within 0.1% or so.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that article is proof of is that the author didn't know how to write good VB.Net code.

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to check though, I'm developing some backup code in vb.net...